# PHP Unicode Character Detection

Tags: php, unicode

I'm trying to get contents from a certain webpage , and replace the next mark : ’  with another substring. It's not a regular apostrophe and even `substr_count($content,"’")` return 0.
It seems like I cannot detect that mark, and therefor can't replace him using substr_replace.

How could I handle this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr-count.php

Comment: Start by specifying what is the character set and encoding of your input. Unicode/UTF-8 most likely?

Comment: BTW, if it *is* UTF-8 then your existing code would work because of how UTF-8 was designed (even though `substr_count` does not support for multibyte encodings). If it does not, that means you need to convert the apostrophe character to its properly encoded equivalent.

Comment: thanks for the answer @Jon, but how could I convert the apostrophe to another encoding ?

Comment: @itamar: Either save your file in the same encoding as your input, or use something like `iconv` to convert from your file encoding to your input encoding, or replace the `’` with its binary representation in your input encoding (for UTF-8 that would be `"\xe2\x80\x99"` -- I found out from [here](http://dev.networkerror.org/utf8/?start=0&end=100&cols=4&search=%E2%80%99&show_uni_int=on&show_uni_hex=on&show_html_ent=on&show_raw_hex=on&show_raw_bin=on)). Any of the three will do; the last one is immune to your file encoding changing, but doesn't show visually what character you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the `$content` and the `’` character in your source code are simply not in the same encoding. `substr_count` compares byte by byte. The `’` character in your source code has the byte representation of however your PHP file is encoded. The `$content` has the encoding of whatever encoding it's in. If the two don't match, the substring won't be found.

Convert the `$content` to some standardized encoding you're working in.

Read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with unicode characters. it's wise to use the multibyte string functions

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr-count.php

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all and many multibyte functions are irrelevant for UTF-8, such as `substr_count`. Sorry but -1

Comment: It does answer the question. As substr_count will probably not work on multibyte characters. So using the mb_* functions is a good idea! You know unicode !== UTF-8.. right?

Comment: Even if someone were to use a non UTF-8 unicode encoding on the web, my point would still apply. `mb_substr_count` vs `substr_count` only makes a difference in encodings such as Shift-Jis.

Comment: I assumed we were handling multibyte characters. Which PHP string functions don't support.

Comment: Given strings `$a` and `$b` that are both encoded in same unicode encoding (in this example UTF-8), this will always evaluate to true: `mb_substr_count($a, $b, "UTF-8") === substr_count($a, $b);`. You can play with it here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/PsNj7Y

Comment: @tlenss "PHP string functions don't support multi-byte strings" is a half-truth. The core functions mostly work on a byte-by-byte basis as opposed to an encoding aware character-by-character basis. This is only relevant in certain circumstances. In this case, it isn't. See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).